# Scrapy ignoring allowed domains

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class LazadaSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "lazada"
    allowed_domains = ['lazada.com.my', 'lazada.co.id', 'lazada.vn', 'lazada.com.ph', 'lazada.co.th', 'lazada.sg']

    def __init__(self, country, *args, **kwargs):
        self.country = country
        super(LazadaSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have start request poping from a redis list which contains mix domains. 
I already enabled the `OffisteMiddleware` inside `settings`

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': 500
   # 'scrapper.middlewares.ScrapperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Is there something i am missing ? Not sure if this is because i am inherting my custom `BaseSpider` rather than `scrapy.Spider`

Comment: How do you know they're being ignored?  Do you get a message somewhere that explicitly says they are ignored, or do they just not show up in the output?

Comment: The logs shows that scrapy still crawling those urls that are not listed in the ```allowed_domains``` for example 
```2017-07-05 17:31:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.blibli.com/adidas-men-training-clmco-bp-backpack-black-aj9721-MTA.0484698.htm?utm_source=affiliates&trans=10226378ed757e49dced1a68a8f392&offer=2&affiliate=Banh+Thu+Phung>```

Comment: Adding on what John said, you also don`t need to set OffsiteMiddleware setting as it is set by default: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#spider-middlewares

Comment: @HenriqueCoura I agree but even without it, still my non allowed urls being crawled. I'll remove this thanks

Comment: Could you edit your post with your Requests? If you set dont_filter=True OffsiteMiddleware will allow them